# Link between abelian groups and endomorphisms

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ho.history-overview

When teaching Algebra, I try to share my fascination about two apparently unrelated questions, which turn out to involve the same theory:

- classifying the finitely generated abelian groups,
- classifying the endomorphism of a vector space, up to similarity.

These problems are solved by using the structure of finitely generated modules over a a principal idea domain, $\mathbb Z$ in the first case, $k[X]$ in the second case.

I presume that these problems were first solved independently from each other. But,

> who discovered that these are two applications of the same theorem ?

Comment: Maybe a clue could be uncovered in a classic algebra text ( such as Van der Waerden's "Modern Algebra")? Priority is often tricky, but I imagine that whoever first proved the structure of fg modules over a PID in something like its modern form would see those two consequences fairly quickly.

Comment: I'm not going to fix the typo "principal idea domain" because I sort of like it as it is.

Comment: @Andreas. Oups! I did not write that way on purpose :)

Comment: @Geoff. I checked Van der Waerden's book. It does not treat modules.

Comment: OK, that is surprising to me- then one has to think of another "classic" text. Herstein's "Topics in Algebra" certainly covers the material, but there must be earlier sources,

Comment: Perhaps Bourbaki.

Comment: The structure theorem goes at least as far back as a 1912 paper of Steinitz in which he proves the structure theorem for f.g. modules over a Dedekind domain. Unfortunately the paper appears to be in German.